# encapsulation redundant Setter

Tags: java, this, setter, getter

I have a coding that I found out recently to contain redundant code. If I leave the `Setter` out (Line18-21) for eg. `sumnr`, it still works perfectly well. So that code seems unnecessary. 
But if I leave `this.sumnr = sumnr;` (Line11) out, and leave the Setter in place, than it does NOT work. Why can't `this.sumnr = sumnr` not be backed-up by the Setter in line18-21??

Anyone a clue?

```java
public class SortSums {
    private int sumnr;
    private int part1;
    private int part2;
    private int result;
    private int answer;
    private String sign;

    public SortSums(int somnr, int part1, int part2, int result, String sign)
    {
        this.sumnr = sumnr;    // LINE11  this line however, seems indispensible. 
        this.part1 = part1;    // idem
        this.part2 = part2;
        this.result = result;
        this.sign = sign;
    }

    public void setSumnr(int sumnr)  // LINE18 it seems that this 'void' method is redundant.
    {
        this.sumnr = sumnr;
    } // LINE21

    public int getSumnr()
    {
        return sumnr;
    }

//etc...
```

Comment: The constructor is for easily setting the *initial* value of the fields. The setter method is for later *changing* the value of the fields. That is not redundant.

Comment: @Andreas If I disable that void part. (Sumnr is a counter that is risen in another part of the code), That sumnr will just get changed than. No matter whether I leave the void Setter or not. It all just seems not clear to me.

Comment: @Twannemannn - I've updated my answer below to address your comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Java never calls setters <s>magically</s> *automatically* behind the scenes (some languages do, or seem to). If you write `this.sumnr = sumnr;` in the constructor, it isn't going to substitute a call to the setter instead. If you have a setter, it isn't going to call it unless you have the actual call to it written in the constructor.

If you wanted to use the setter on line 11, you'd need to replace it with:

```
this.setSumnr(sumnr);
```

Calling methods from within the constructor generally isn't best practice, though (although some folks think setters are an exemption to that rule; others don't).

> If I leave the Setter out (Line18-21) for eg. sumnr, it still works perfectly well. So that code seems unnecessary.

Not necessarily. It depends entirely on whether you want to allow changing `sumnr` after the `SortSums` object is created. If you do, you'll want to have the setter. If you don't, leave it out.

Andreas said it very well in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566368/encapsulation-redundant-setter#comment105300802_59566368_): The constructor is for setting the initial value of the field. The setter is for changing that value to something else later if desired.

In a comment you've said:

> If I disable that void part. (Sumnr is a counter that is risen in another part of the code), That sumnr will just get changed than. No matter whether I leave the void Setter or not. It all just seems not clear to me.

Right. You don't need a setter to change the value of your `sumnr` field from within the `SortSums` code; you can just assign to it directly. The purpose of the setter is to allow code **outside** of `SortSums` to set the `sumnr` field **if you want that to be possible**. If you don't want it to be possible, leave off the setter.

Let's make this simpler.

With a setter, code outside the class can change the field directly:

```
class WithSetter {
    private int value;

    public WithSetter(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void incrementValue() {
        ++this.value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class ExampleWith {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var w = new WithSetter(0);
        w.incrementValue();
        System.out.println(w.getValue()); // 1
        w.setValue(7);                           // <=== Works just fine
        System.out.println(w.getValue()); // 7
    }
}
```

It's not really the code outside the class doing it, of course; it's the code in the setter that's doing it. But the setter can be called from outside the class.

Without a setter, code outside the class can't set the value directly:

```
class WithoutSetter {
    private int value;

    public WithoutSetter(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void incrementValue() {
        ++this.value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class ExampleWithOut {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var w = new WithoutSetter(0);
        w.incrementValue();
        System.out.println(w.getValue()); // 1
        w.setValue(7);                           // <=== Won't compile
        w.value = 7;                             // <=== Also won't compile
        System.out.println(w.getValue());
    }
}
```

In `WithoutSetter`, **only** code within the class can change `value`. No code outside the class can (without using reflection, but that's a different topic).

Comment: So Java magically calls the constructor behind the scenes? At least that what I read that first statement to imply. Please clarify.

Comment: @Andreas - Huh. I've tried to clarify. (Great [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566368/encapsulation-redundant-setter#comment105300802_59566368), btw. I added it and CW'd the post.)

Comment: @Andreas - Man, that was sloppy, thanks. (You're always welcome to fix obvious typos/editing errors directly. But just pointing them out is fine too.)

Comment: I find that having programmers fix their own mistakes helps ensure they learn from them.  Not that we all need to learn much from typos. Those will continue to happen, which is why we use IDEs to help us mere humans along. 